# How can I create a convincing sea material in Cycles without using the ocean modifier?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials

I'm trying to render a sea scene animation, but using the ocean modifier and huge subdivisions isn't feasible due to the large scale. Luckily it's a calm sea and seen from quite a distance, but there still should be some kind of animated movement or shimmer you can see on a real water surface. Is it possible to do something like this in cycles?

The render shows what I currently have which is just a translucent plane with a seafloor material beneath and a slightly rough reflection of the cloud environment map.[image]

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Expanding on [Róbert László Páli's answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/3225/599), this is possible with a [*Procedural texture*](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/shader_nodes/textures/index.html) and bump mapping.

## Texture

For an ocean texture, the procedural textures most likely to be what you want are:

- **[Noise](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/shader_nodes/textures/noise.html#noise-texture-node):**

  [image: Noise example]
- **[Wave](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/shader_nodes/textures/wave.html#wave-texture-node):**

  [image: Wave example]
- **[Voronoi](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/shader_nodes/textures/voronoi.html#voronoi-texture-node):**

  [image: Voronoi example]
- **[Musgrave](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/shader_nodes/textures/musgrave.html#musgrave-texture-node):**

  [image: Musgrave example]

You can also combine and mix these with an [*RGB mix*](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/shader_nodes/color/mix.html#mix-node) node.

## Displacement

Here are some examples of bump mapping with a [*Noise texture*](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/shader_nodes/textures/noise.html#noise-texture-node):

You can affect only certain shaders by using the *Bump* node. One advantage to the bump node is you can easily adjust the strength of the displacement:

[image: bump node example]

Or you can affect the entire material by plugging the texture output directly into the [*Displacement*](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/shader_nodes/vector/displacement.html#displacement-node) input of the *Material Output* node:

[image: displacement setup]

To control the strength with this method, plug the noise texture into an *MixRGB* node and set it to multiply. The other input becomes the "Strength factor", where white is full displacement (you can set it to a value greater than white to get a larger displacement), and black is no displacement. (likewise, negative values produce an inverted displacement)

[image: Using a MixRGB node]

## Animating

This effect can be animated over time by animating the location of the *Texture space*. The settings for the *Texture space* are located in *Properties > Object data panel > Texture space*:

[image: texture space settings]

You can interactivle move the *Texture space* in the 3D view with <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>T</kbd>.

Note that you most likely want to animate along the Z, otherwise it will look like it's a static surface sliding horizontally.

You may also want to set the interpolation type to *Linear* in the *Graph editor* by pressing <kbd>T</kbd>*> Linear* to make the *texture space* move at a constant speed without accelerating and decelerating (the default behavior):

[image]

Result:

[image]

Comment: Could you post your shader/.blend for the ocean, I can never get water looking that good :P.

Comment: @GiantCowFilms It's already in the answer (it's just a glossy shader with an HDR sky). Here's the [.blend](http://www.pasteall.org/blend/30641) anyway. If you want something a little more realistic you might try using a volume shader like [this](http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/7669/599).

Comment: @gandal3 Thanks, I thought it would have been more complex :)

Comment: Great explanation of the different procedural texture types. If SE had a best list this answer would be on it. Well written and laid out.

Answer (score 3):

You could do that by adding a procedural texture, and plug the output into the displace for the material (in the node editor view). You might try a noise texture (in Cycles it looks like a Cloud texture in BI), add a Mapping node, and for the x coordinate set the scale to 2 maybe, and set z rotation to the prefered. Try it, tweak it. There are more sophisticated texture for oceans, maybe a tilabe image could be used, but for this scene it might be ok, or as a strating point.