# Display bounding box around objects

Tags: interface, 3d-view, objects

I would like to know how to display a Bounding Box around my objects in Blender, much like the Bounding Box from Maya 3D. All I want to be able to do is determine the outer edges of an object.

I've looked everywhere in the interface, but cannot see how to turn that on.

Comment: Please give more details - is this bounding box for display only? or do you intend to use for something else?

Comment: I only want to see the edges of the object I'm modeling. For example, if I want to model a chair that is 3 feet tall, then I would add my 3 foot tall Bounding box and then begin to model within that. It would be like having one object in wireframe mode and the others in solid mode, the Bounding Box being the wireframe object.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Assuming you just want to display a bounding box around or instead of each object, you can do this with *Draw types*.

## Drawing a bounding box instead of the object:

You could set [*Viewport shading*](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/3D_interaction/Navigating/3D_View_Options) to *Bounding box* to draw the bounds of each object:

[image]

A comparison between *Solid* and *Bounding box*:

[image] 
[image]

To do this for one object only, you can set this in *Properties > Object Display > Maximum draw type*:

[image]

[image]

## Drawing a bounding box around the object:

This can be done by enabling *Bounds* with the *Maximum draw type* still higher than *Bounds*:

[image]

This looks like this:

[image]

You could do this for many objects by:

1. Select the objects for which you want to enable *Bounding box*
2. Enable *Bounds* in *Object > Display*
3. Right click on the *Bounds* option and select *Copy to selected*:

   [image]

[image]

Comment: I think you got it...I want to do the "Drawing a bounding box around the object" option. That's what I needed. THANK YOU !!!

Comment: Just tested it....PERFECT. I actually like "Texture Space" a little better, because I can use that in Edit Mode, whereas Bound - Box is only visible in Object Mode. VERY GOOD!!! Thanks again.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure how to vote for the answer yet, given that I'm new here, but this is my selected answer.

Comment: @Calixto keep in mind that the [*Texture space*](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Textures/Mapping) is something different, so while it works for this, you may have problems if you want to change the texture space location or scale. (e.g. for something like [this](http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/3223/599)

Answer (score 6):

[@Gandalf3](https://blender.stackexchange.com/users/599/gandalf3) [answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/3367/132229) still applies, this is just update for Blender 2.9+.

In Blender 2.9+, to display an object's bounding box, you have to select it (in viewport or through the outliner) and then go to *Object Properties Tab > Viewport Display*.

There you'll find the option *Display As* with *Textured* option selected by default. To display the bounding box, you just have to pick the *Bounds* option, as seen in the picture bellow.

[image]

You can display both the object and its bounding box. You can achieve this by selecting *Textured* option and enable *Bounds* checkbox.