# Overal dimensions of objects

Tags: units

I've made the model of a table, actually it consists of 3 objects (i need to keep them as separate) is there any way how I can see the overal dimensions (actually I  need to get the height) of all objects that the table consists of ? After selecting objects the panel on the right shows the dimensions of the bigest object one.
[image]

Thx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could enable edge or face infos in *Edit Mode* it would display the measures for the selected edges/faces since only one object is active in *Edit Mode* you can only pick one.

Although you can set *Viewport Shading* to bounding box there is no option to display the length.

[image]

Related:

- [How to model effectively using exact measurements?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/274/what-are-some-best-practices-when-modelling-with-exact-measurements)
- [Display bounding box around objects](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/3366/display-bounding-box-around-objects)