# avoiding a tiled looking ocean simulation

Tags: modifiers, ocean-simulation

I want to make a scene of a missile flying over the ocean. Because I want the missile to be relatively high up, the ocean looks very repetitive.

How can I make the ocean not look tiled without scaling up the object and making the waves smaller?

[image]

Comment: You can't really.

Comment: You could try adding subtle variations, perhaps with another ocean modifier set to *deform*. However, at this height you probably don't need actual mesh displacement, you can [probably get away with some bump-mapping](http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/3223/599).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you aren't going to see the ocean very close up, I wouldn't use the ocean modifier for this at all.

Instead you can probably get a reasonable result using a simple plane and some bump-mapping:

[image]

[image]

See [How can I create a convincing sea material in Cycles without using the ocean modifier?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/3223/599) for more details.

---

That said, if you still want to use the ocean modifier, you could try adding multiple *displace* ocean modifiers with different settings after the initial modifier.

Try varying settings like the *time*  and *spatial size* between modifiers.

Here's an example with three displace ocean modifiers after a generate ocean modifier, each with different a time and spatial size:

[image]