# How can I make this render more realistic

Tags: modeling, animation, texturing

I'm having this project with a company that I have to make an animation for them, I've started learning Blender for this project and I'm still consider myself very noob in Blender, specially in terms of texturing and UV mapping.
I've rendered this shot just now, and I still think it's not exactly what I wanted.

Note 1: I'm using texture and bump for the ocean because the Blender ocean simulator is just killing RAM, and I can't get it done for the big scale ocean like this, is there anyway (or other ways) to make the ocean look real?

[image]

I have an underwater scene which I don't exactly know how i should make it look real, but I'm still trying. I'm having a very hard time getting the volume texture for underwater scene!

[image]

The other issue I have is the boat trails, currently I'm using an static image that looks like a trail, but it's an animation and the trail is static which makes no sense. What are the other options to create this trail?

[image]

I accept any comments, suggestions & criticism so please shoot!

Comment: You should put this on Blender Artist under "Focused Critiques" thread..

Comment: thanks @Jerryno i've just submitted it to blender artist, it's not showing yet , i think it has to be moderated

Comment: Yep I think if you are new there first 3 post have to be moderated then it works normally..

Comment: As @Jerryno said, this is a better fit for BA because it could be considered off topic here, as it is kind of opinion based or even to narrow. We prefer that questions on this site are objective and have a definitive answers, because it works better with the SE format.

Comment: Welcome to the site :) I think these can be formatted as valid questions, especially as you tried things out first :) But on this site we try to keep to one question per post. Try splitting your post up into separate questions (e.g. "how to get a realistic underwater volume shader" etc.). Also some of your questions might already have answers, or at least tips in the right direction.  See http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/26596/599, http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/3223/599, and http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/17787/599.