# Edge of background image is visible

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine

[image][image][image]

Why does the edge continue to show up on my background mountains?  I'm using alpha but I can't get the edge to not show up.  Thanks.

Comment: Ooo that is quite a cool scene! It would probably [look better in cycles](http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/3229/3127) though  (most things do). Anyway, could you post a .blend file or screenshots of  your materials and textures, it would really help us figure out which of many quirks in blender is causing the problem, and how to fix it!

Comment: If I figure out how to post a file, I will include the .blend

Comment: @user11510 use http://pasteall.org/blend and share the link here. Make sure to pack everything in the file. Use File > External Data > Pack all into .blend.

Comment: Here you go http://pasteall.org/blend/34298

Comment: @user11510 Found a solution

Answer (score 3):

The issue was that your image was duplicating at the top, Under image mapping change the drop down from *repeat* to *extend*.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  I tried premultipled and repeating and those didn't work but the I tried Extend  under Extension in the Image Mapping tab and it worked.

Comment: @user11510 Thanks for pointing that out, I knew there was an option somewhere, but didn't find it, since it has been many many months since I last used the internal render engine. If the answer helped you (or now correctly answers the question), please mark it as accepted using the check mark.