# I want to make "god rays" in my nature scene

Tags: volumetrics

I am now busy with my first nature scene ever in cycles but I can't seem to get the hang of god rays for my scene, in a very simple scene with just a window I got it to work but it doesn't work out for this scene, I watched every tutorial I could find but still then it doesn't work, so you guys are sort of my last resort :), see the images for my settings and scene

[image: My non rendered scene (with volumetrics box)]
[image: My rendered scene]
And my goal is to get god rays through the trees.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Unrelated to the question, but related to your scene: [cycles water](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/3229/30849).